# Problem using triple integrals and the directional derivative

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vectors

Sorry for the vague question, but I'm so lost on this problem I don't even really know what it's asking of me. If anyone could show me how to do it I would appreciate it so much. All I can think of is integrating the density function with cylindrical coordinates, with $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$, $r$ from $0$ to $1$ and z from $0$ to $2$ but I have no idea if any of this is right.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Could you post the actual problem?

Comment: This is the actual problem!

Answer (score 1):

As a start, you can convert the density to cylindrical coordinates:

$$\rho(r, \phi, z) = \frac{z + 2 r^2 \cos^2 \phi}{1 + r^2}$$

Then you can split the integrand into two terms and integrate each part with the limits you specified in the question, which are correct.  Splitting it up will allow you to make use of the hint at the end of the question for one of the parts.  (The volume element will be $r\cdot dr \cdot d\phi \cdot dz.$)

Can you take it from here?  I think you're on the right track.

Comment: Yes, that helps a ton. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It's an elaborate way of asking for the integral of the given function over a cylinder-shaped region. The function has the same cylinder symmetry.

Comment: Thanks! Would it be correct then, to integrate with theta from 0 to 2pi, r from 0 to 1 and z from 0 to 2?

Comment: That is correct.